# SSMS 2008 Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '2.126' to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssms

I'm new to SQL and I'm using SQL Server 2008 Management Studio. The below code isn't working due to a decimal being converted to an `INT`. From similar issues I can see that I need to use `CONVERT`, but unsure how to use this in my code?

```
DROP TABLE [DBO].[STEP9_OUTPUT]
GO

SELECT      
    S8.*,
    CAST(CASE
            WHEN S8.ERROR_TRANSACTION = 'N'
               THEN NOERROR_VALUE
            WHEN S8.SOURCE_SYSTEM_IND = 'P'
               THEN P_VALUE
            ELSE A_VALUE
         END AS FLOAT) AS CORRECTED_PRICE
INTO STEP9_OUTPUT
FROM
    (SELECT      
         S8.*,
         CASE
            WHEN S8.SOURCE_SYSTEM_IND = 'P' AND DIVRATE = 'Y'
               THEN P_VALUE_DIV
            WHEN S8.SOURCE_SYSTEM_IND = 'P' AND DIVRATE = 'N'
               THEN P_VALUE_MULT
            ELSE NULL
         END AS P_VALUE
     FROM
         (SELECT      
              S8.*,
              CASE
                  WHEN S8.SOURCE_SYSTEM_IND = 'P' AND 
                       S8.ERROR_TRANSACTION = 'Y' AND 
                       DIVRATE = 'N' AND S8.FN > 0
                     THEN S8.FN
                  WHEN S8.UNITS_INFUND_FOR_TRADE > 0 
                     THEN S8.FTP
                  WHEN S8.FJFG = 'N' AND S8.RATE IS NULL
                     THEN S8.FB / 100 * 1
                  WHEN S8.FJFG = 'N' AND S8.RATE IS NOT NULL
                     THEN S8.FB / 100 * S8.RATE
                  WHEN S8.FJFG <> 'N' AND S8.RATE IS NULL
                     THEN 1 * 1
                  WHEN S8.FJFG <> 'N' AND S8.RATE IS NOT NULL
                     THEN 1 * S8.RATE
                  ELSE NULL
               END AS P_VALUE_MULT,
               CASE
                  WHEN S8.SOURCE_SYSTEM_IND = 'P' AND 
                       S8.ERROR_TRANSACTION = 'Y' AND 
                       [DIVRATE] = 'Y' AND S8.FN > 0
                     THEN S8.FN
                  WHEN S8.UNITS_INFUND_FOR_TRADE > 0
                     THEN S8.FTP
                  WHEN S8.FJFG = 'N' AND S8.RATE IS NULL
                     THEN S8.FB / 100
                  WHEN S8.FJFG = 'N' AND S8.RATE IS NOT NULL
                     THEN S8.FB / (100 / S8.RATE)
                  ELSE NULL
               END AS P_VALUE_DIV
           FROM
               (SELECT      
                    S8.*,
                    CASE
                        WHEN S8.ERROR_TRANSACTION = 'N'
                           THEN FUND_UNIT_PRICE_FOR_TRADE
                        ELSE NULL
                    END AS NOERROR_VALUE,
                    CASE
                       WHEN S8.SOURCE_SYSTEM_IND = 'A' AND
                            S8.ERROR_TRANSACTION = 'Y' AND 
                            S8.ASSET_CODE = 'XX'
                          THEN S8.FUND_BID_VALUE
                       ELSE NULL
                    END AS A_VALUE,
                    CASE
                       WHEN S8.FACURR = 'SEK' OR S8.FACURR = 'JPY'
                          THEN 'Y'
                       ELSE 'N'
                    END AS DIVRATE
                FROM 
                    STEP8_OUTPUT S8) S8
      ) S8
) S8
```

Comment: Start with reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CAST(CAST('2.126' as decimal) as int)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, where would I place this in my code?  I tried at the end and then the begining but both return the same error message as before.  Thanks.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, please provide additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question to improve its long-term value.